# Get rid of magnifying glass in iOS web app

Tags: css, ios, html, web-applications

I am currently exploring web apps for iOS devices and use PhoneGap to create a "native" application out of it. The problem I have with this is the magnifying glass, that I don't want to be shown when selecting paragraphs (or bit of text). I have tried a lot of solutions but nether works. I use this CSS to disable all copy, selection and such for those fields I wan't:

```
*[untouchable] {
    -webkit-user-drag: none;
    -webkit-user-modify: none;
    -webkit-highlight: none;

    -webkit-touch-callout:  none;
    -webkit-user-select:    none;
    -khtml-user-select:     none;
    -moz-user-select:       none;
    -ms-user-select:        none;
    -o-user-select:         none;
    user-select:            none;
}
```

This works fine, but it still shows the magnifer/loupe when I touch and hold on text:

[image: Touch + hold shows magnifier on text]

Is there a real solution to this? It would be awesome with a simple CSS property such like `-webkit-magnifier: none` or something like that. If there's a JavaScript solution, that would be fine too, but maybe a overkill.

Since I am using PhoneGap and it uses UIWebView to show the page, there might be a way of disabling the magnifier for that - but I haven't looked that much into the native source.

Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: this worked perfectly for me. I used the CSS selector *. Thank you. ACCEPT more ANSWERS!

Comment: hi fnky,I am facing the same problem,did u find any solution for it?,Thanks

Answer (score 4):

The only way to accomplish this is to rid elements completely of selection since the magnifier is incorporated. `-webkit-user-select:none;` should be applied to all elements where you don't want the magnifier to appear.

Comment: You can see in the `untouchable` element there's already applied the `-webkit-user-select:none;` property - so why won't it work?

Comment: You also have -webkit-user-callout set to none, so I am unsure what your problem might be. Be sure to set these properties to the correct elements and check over your CSS for any missed errors.

Comment: I confirm that you both need "-webkit-user-callout: none;" and "-webkit-user-select: none;" to disable the magnifying glass

Comment: @Max, I have same problem in my phonegap application but it didn't work. Is there something I am missing out?

Answer (score 3):

This is what I used

```
* {
        -webkit-touch-callout: none;
        -webkit-user-callout: none;
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        -webkit-user-drag: none;
        -webkit-user-modify: none;
        -webkit-highlight: none;
}
```